# re get text between braces

Tags: python, regex, python-re

**Data**

```
module All
{

    obj Bucket
    {
        Damage = 900
        Type = Weapon
        Cooldown = 2
        Craftable = false
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
"Bucket": {
    Damage: 900
    Type: Weapon
    Cooldown: 2
    Craftable: false
}
```

**Current Code**

```
def get_object(x):
    pattern = r'\{+(.*?)\}'
    
    return re.findall(pattern, x, re.MULTILINE) # returns []
```

I want to get the data between the { }, this code works for eg. "{ text }" but not for this string, maybe it's because of the newlines, I don't know much regex so any help is appreciated!

Comment: This data looks like it's structured in some language. Is there no library for parsing whatever that language is? That would be more appropriate than a regex here.

Comment: You need `re.S` (or dotall), not multiline. `re.findall(r"\{[^{}]*\}",x,re.S)` works for me.

Comment: If you can, consider using one of the data formats that Python has modules for in the standard library. For example [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) or [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this pattern

```
(?<=obj\s)(\w+)(?:.*?)(\{.*?\})
```

Also, see the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lxdpyk/1)

##### Python Example

```
import re

text = """module All
{

    obj Bucket
    {
        Damage = 900
        Type = Weapon
        Cooldown = 2
        Craftable = false
    }
}"""

result = re.search(r"(?<=obj\s)(\w+)(?:.*?)(\{.*?\})", text, re.S)
if result:
    key, value = result.groups()
    print(f'"{key}": {value}')
```

##### Output

```
"Bucket": {
        Damage = 900
        Type = Weapon
        Cooldown = 2
        Craftable = false
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want the contents of the inner {}.

With this regex it should be possible: `\{([\w\s\n=]*)\}`

Input:

```
module All
{

    obj Bucket
    {
        Damage = 900
        Type = Weapon
        Cooldown = 2
        Craftable = false
    }
}
```

Output:

```
        Damage = 900
        Type = Weapon
        Cooldown = 2
        Craftable = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option without `re.MULTILINE` or `re.S` flags or lookarounds, using a  [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

```
\bobj[^\S\n]+(\w+)\n\s*({[^}]*})
```

**Explanation**

- `\bobj` Match the word `obj` preceded by a word boundary
- `[^\S\n]+` Match 1+ spaces without newlines
- `(\w+)` Capture *group 1*, match 1+ word characters
- `\n\s*` Match a newline and optional whitespace char
- `({[^}]*})` Capture *group 2*, match optional chars other than `{` and `}` and then match `}`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hR3NW6/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"\bobj[^\S\n]+(\w+)\n\s*({[^}]*})"

s = ("module All\n"
            "{\n\n"
            "    obj Bucket\n"
            "    {\n"
            "        Damage = 900\n"
            "        Type = Weapon\n"
            "        Cooldown = 2\n"
            "        Craftable = false\n"
            "    }\n"
            "}")

m = re.search(pattern, s)
if m:
    print(f'"{m.group(1)}": {m.group(2)}')
```

**Output**

```
"Bucket": {
        Damage = 900
        Type = Weapon
        Cooldown = 2
        Craftable = false
    }
```